# Mass Effect 3 - Best ending after missing some time sensitive missions

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just missed some time sensitive missions, but I guess I'm doing well with the other assets:

- Collector's base intact
- Rachni Queen saved
- Genophage cured
- Council saved

The missions that I didn't complete are the ones I should've done before the Priority: Tuchanka part of the game.

Should I go back (lose around 5 hours of game) or can I keep on moving forward and compensate these lost points through Galaxy readiness on the multiplayer mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Provided you haven't messed up/missed out on many other assets, you should be able to get the "best" ending with sufficiently high galactic readiness. You need 5000 effective war assets, how much total war assets do you have now?

Comment: I think I was around 2400 when I finished the mission the Citadel. I might have to double check on that.

Comment: If you have the Extended Cut DLC installed, I think you only need somewhere around 3000 for the best ending.

Answer (score 0):

Got around 4000 now, just by doing side missions after Priority: Citadel (2), so I guess it's not a problem.